# What does "weighted pass" mean in soccer sense?

Tags: meaning

> With roughly 15 minutes remaining in the first half, Christian Volesky was in clean on goal after a well-**weighted pass** in the right channel from Matt Polster, but didn't get the contact he wanted and allowed the Louisville goalkeeper to save.

Does it just mean its a good pass? or actually this is a type of technique in soccer?

Comment: This helped me learning more about the word *weighted* than I already knew about it. +1 Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *weighted pass* means you are passing the ball – not to the place where the player *is*, but to the place where your moving teammate *will be*:

> A good **weighted** ball is played into space in front of your teammate making it quite easy for them to run on to it in stride.
>
> <sup>[Source](http://www.soccer-training-methods.com/weighted-pass.html)</sup>

The term isn't necessarily only used in football; I found this in a rugby book:

> If the first receiver is to be the springboard of the attack, it is his responsibility to control the movements of the defence and to give a **perfectly-weighted pass** to a runner in the gap created.
>
> <sup>Source: Bert Holcroft, *Book 2: Futuristic Rugby League: Academy of Excellence For Coaching Rugby Skills and Fitness Drills*</sup>

and this one is from a recap of an ice hockey game:

> Andres split the Notre Dame defense with a brilliantly **weighted pass** that found the stick of Reynolds, who was gliding toward the goal.
>
> <sup>[Source](http://www.nj.com/times-sports/index.ssf/2014/02/notre_dame_advances_to_mercer.html)</sup>

The blue line in this diagram shows the trajectory of a weighted pass:

[image]

You can watch the execution of the pass at [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ecJgIiWnmxU).

Comment: Excellent..I must include this word. Thanks for this J.R. I really appreciate. I tried hard to get this merely looking the definitions in various dictionaries. Ah, *well-awaited* also works...what say ;) Also, can you enlighten me with this as well? *was **in clean on** goal..* Why *in*? _was clean_ also works...

Comment: I disagree about _well-awaited_, because _awaited_ might imply the receiver is stationary, **waiting** for the pass (unless you mean it's well-awaited by the fans, who are hoping for a chance to cheer). As for the preposition, I agree with you, it's not needed, but it does indicate the direction of the player (_in_ in this context meaning _toward_), so it's not wrong, either.

Comment: No no...well-awaited, not in that sense. Something like *a well/much-awaited* pass from someone. Everybody was waiting for that. Something like *Well/much-awaited movie Amazing Spiderman -II*. Much-awaited from the perspective of the team and its fans. And thanks for clarifying that prep

Comment: +1 I've learned a new phrase! It might also be mentioned that this is not used with US football (at least I've never encountered it). Instead, we speak of the passer *leading* the receiver: Warner **led** Bruce perfectly; he streaked under the pass without breaking stride and loped effortlessly another twenty yards into the end zone.

Answer (score 4):

The "weight" of a pass is how hard you hit the ball. As far as English language is concerned, the meaning is because of the association between weight and force.

> Weight of pass is key:
>   The speed of the ball is crucial to a successful pass

http://performance.fourfourtwo.com/technique/xavi-master-the-pass

A "well-weighted pass" is one that has the correct weight for the situation. It's usually used when the pass must be neither too fast nor too slow in order to work. Of course, with Xavi's standard and style of play this is all passes ;-) A pass hit forward as hard as possible is not usually referred to as "well-weighted" even when it's correct to hit it that hard.

Note that a "well-weighted pass" is a pass that is "well-weighted", not a "weighted pass" that is well :-)

It is most important to weight the pass correctly when passing into space, hence the meaning given by J.R, that a "weighted pass" is a pass where the ball meets a team-mate running onto it. That is to say, a pass where the weight is just as important as the direction and flight. Too hard and your team-mate won't reach it. Too slow and there may be a defender in position to cut it off, or even the best outcome your team-mate must break stride to collect it.

Answer (score 0):

**Well-weighted pass**, means a well thought and professionally carried out action. In other words the player was able to see the opportunity for this action and played it successfully.

Comment: Can you get us the source of this definition? The word *weighted* looks tricky to me here.